# autoplot saves blank plot to png device when chained within data.table

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table

I have a `data.table` with a column with forecasts of some values, and I want to save plots of each of those forecasts with `ggplot2::autoplot`.

I'm attempting this (reproducible example):

```
require(data.table)
require(forecast)
require(ggplot2)

## create data.table
a <- data.table(id = 1:2)
a[, x := .(list(sample(1:10, 5, FALSE))), by = id]
a[, y := .(list(forecast(x[[1]]))), by = id]

## plot by id:
a[, {png(paste0(id, ".png")); autoplot(y[[1]]); dev.off()}, by = id]
```

but it creates blank canvases.

However, the following code works:

```
png("1.png")
a[1, autoplot(y[[1]])]
dev.off()
```

Which makes me think that it's something with the chaining of commands inside the `{}`. The next code also works (since `plot` doesn't work with forecast objects, I'm plotting the `x` variable:

```
a[, {png(paste0(id, ".png")); plot([[1]]); dev.off()}, by = id]
```

which makes me think of `autoplot`.

What am I doing wrong, and what would be the way to effectively achieve what I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without looking into `autoplot` code, the difference between those two expressions is a hidden `print` which happens in the 2nd case, since that expression returns the object created by `autoplot`, which then R core "prints" (which can mean different things for different objects).

Thus the fix is in calling `print` yourself:

```
a[, {png(paste0(id, ".png")); print(autoplot(y[[1]])); dev.off()}, by = id]
```